# A basic question on infinite product converging to zero

Tags: real-analysis

Is the product $\prod_{n=1} ^{\infty} a_n = 0$ if $0<a_n<1 \forall n$ ?

Comment: Technically, [infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) are said to *diverge* to $0$. Furthermore, an infinite product $\displaystyle\prod(1\pm a_k)$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle\sum a_k$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take the product form for the zeta function for example,

$$\zeta(s) = \prod (1-\frac{1}{p^s})^{-1},$$

For real $s >1$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take $a_n = 2^{-\frac{1}{2^n}}$. Then the product is $\frac 1 2$.